# How to avoid, that URL.equals needs access to the internet in Java?

Tags: java, url, dns, equals, equality

The `equals()` method of the URL class in the Java class library makes a DNS request to get the IP for the hostname, to check the two IP's for equality. This happens even for URLs that are created from the same `String`. Is there a way to avoid this internet access?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) instead of URL.

Comment: And of course this makes semantic sense too, because you want to compare the Identifiers rather than the Locations

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to compare the url strings, try

```
url1.toString().equals(url2.toString())
```

Comment: The two strings could be vastly different but point to the same resource.

Comment: If you want to check the resource referred to by a URL, you obviously need internet access.  Therefore I made the assumption that he wanted to compare the urls themselves.  Hence my qualification of "if you just want to compare the url strings".

Answer (score 1):

Don't use URL.equals. As the documentation says,

> Note: The defined behavior for `equals` is known to be inconsistent with virtual hosting in HTTP.

Comment: How should I test for equality?

Comment: You can use toString() or toExternalForm() to get the external form, and compare those. Preliminary testing here shows it doesn't access DNS.

Comment: I just upvoted Bill's answer. Just call toURI() on your URL objects.